# What is the proper way to upgrade Scrapy on a mac

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to upgrade Scrapy v 0.18.4 to the latest version which I believe is 0.20.0 on a mac. I do not see in the docs how I should go about doing so.

I tried running `pip install --upgrade Scrapy` however my Scrapy version still reads 0.18.4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you solved the problem with a local install.

For what it's worth, the approach that you used in the original post should work.  Scrapy v0.20.0 is the current release on PyPI and that is the correct pip command for a package upgrade.  I just verified that a fresh install of v0.20.0 with pip works fine on Mac OSX running Mavericks. If it is still in your history, it would be worth a glance at the log from the pip install attempt to see if there were any errors, and if there were not, determine where the 0.20.0 version was installed.  You may be running into issues with your shell or Python PATH settings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading the library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy to a directory (my desktop) then cd into the directory and ran

> sudo python setup.py install

It installed the library and I am good to go running version 0.20.0